# Which datatype is better for mapping purposes in python?, Object or Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, mapping

I recently learnt about objects and dictionaries in python?
Which is better suited for mapping purposes,
Below given is an object

```
class frontend:
    python_included = "no"
    html_included = "yes"
    css_included = "yes"
    js_included = "yes"
    java_included = "no"
    c++_included = "no"
```

How to access an objects properties is given below

```
print("Is html a frontend language: ", frontend.html_included, "Is python a frontend language: ", frontend.python_included)
```

Below given is a dictionary

```
python_included = None
html_included = None
css_included = None
js_included = None
java_included = None
c++_included = None

frontend = {
    python_included: "no"
    html_included: "yes"
    css_included: "yes"
    js_included: "yes"
    java_included: "no"
    c++_included = "no"
}
```

How to access a dictionary's properties is given below

```
print("Is html a frontend language: ", frontend[html_included], "Is python a frontend language: ", frontend[python_included])
```

For me they seem the same, Is that the case?, or is it something deeper which I don't know about?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: wait until you learn about `TypedDict` then its going to be really confusing. All jokes aside they are not the same. Yes accessing can be similar but what about adding a dynamic number of members? looping the members? deleting members? all these can be easily done with dict and hacked together using setattr and getattr for classes. But its not clean. I can also store 1 in an int or '1' in a string and they look the same but there are places to use the one and places to use the other

Comment: Your example is wrong. The dictionary keys would probably be strings.

Comment: See also [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Comment: Dictionaries are actually a child of object, but they add a lot of pleasantries for mapping/set logic in the same way that lists add features for iterating, strings string operations, ints/floats math etc etc

Comment: @PeterWood No actually dictionary keys can be of almost any type

Comment: hashable types since its a hashmap

Comment: @StackMan99 dictionary keys can be any hashable type, I know. But probably what you're looking for is strings. Otherwise, in your example, what type is `python_included`, and what is its value?

Comment: There are many differences in preference if you've worked with them long enough. For one, you'd definitely prefer a dictionary if you have arbitrary keys that you need to check if they exist (since its a hashmap). Of course, in unslotted classes, instances would have an underlying `__dict__` dictionary but that would be cumbersome and you'd be better off with a dictionary.

Comment: Classes on the other hand are more for cases where you have known attributes that you want to make known or perhaps add some functionality on them (adding methods). Again, because of how python works, unslotted classes can have new attributes assigned to them that weren't originally included. But you get the general idea.